# How to set my empty string data to become zero in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I wanted to ask you guys if there is an answer to my query.

My query is this, in my table I want to save an empty string "" value and save it to my MySQL table but I wanted to have it as 0 value. here is an illustration

```
Table  ->   MySQL
  ""          0
```

thank you

Comment: Can't you just set the default value to 0 so if nothing gets inserted into that field, it add 0?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, do:

```
if($string == "")
    $string = 0;
```

And then use it in your MySQL query. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make trigger ON BEFORE INSERT\UPDATE

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER trigger_name
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.field_name = "" THEN 
    SET NEW.field_name = 0;
  END IF;

END
```

Better to do it on the client side...

Comment: Is there a way where I will not use a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

In your database if the column is defined with datatype 'int' then passing ''(empty string) will have mysql insert it as 0.

Example :

```
insert into table_name (`column_name`) values ('');
```

Comment: yes my data type is int, my values is set to for example name = ?

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific?